# Is the cross-validation a goodness-of-fit test?

Tags: cross-validation, goodness-of-fit

I read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) on the Goodness of fit(GOF) and it explains GOF as

> **The goodness of fit of a statistical model describes how well it fits**
>   **a set of observations.** Measures of goodness of fit typically summarize
>   the discrepancy between observed values and the values expected under
>   the model in question.

I look at the description and I think that the cross-validation does the same thing as GOF. But I never heard of anyone describing the cross-validation as the GOF test.

Could cross-validation be considered as a GOF test and if it's not, what is the reason?

Comment: I thought cross-validation was a model tuning or hyperparameter estimation technique.  It might also be use to predict future out-of-model errors but will tend to be biased, and you might want to regard those predictions as a goodness-of-fit measure

Comment: @Henry While cv is used for the model selection, it performs the task by calculating the cost function which is the measure of fit. I understand your point. People may think of cv as more than the goodness of fit. But in the end, it's a model validation tool, I think, as the name indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The main difference is that CV attempts to emulate out of sample performance of the model while GoF tests are in sample. Roughly speaking GoF looks at the fit to entire sample while CV fits to a subset then compares the fit with the other part of dataset

Comment: IMHO **attempts** needs to be emphasized. One of the most frequent mistakes I encounter with CV are incorrect splitting procedures (that do not take into account e.g. repeated measurements) - these will effectively degrage the CV result to an elaborate goodness of fit test.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX in fact the way most people use CV turn it into an extension of estimation. when you run thousands of different models and use CV on each of them to select best, it's not much different from the main path of estimation. hence this practice undermines stated objective of CV to address overfitting. using CV this way one can overfit as well as without CV. however, this is not what OP was asking about